# Problem when concatenating formatted string

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting

```
 currTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("u");
```

The code above first formats the time now to `yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss` (Alpha numerical).

I wanted to remove the alpha numerical character so I used

```
 currTime = currTime.Substring(0, currTime.Length - 1);
```

I then added ".000" to the end using

```
 currTime = currTime + ".000";
```

However, this then removes the formatting and when displayed shows the standard `dd-mm-yyyy` format. So my question is in two parts:

So...

How do I format `DateTime.Now` to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` without the alpha numerical character?

And how to add ".000" without losing my format?

Comment: Incidentally, the standard format is closer to the yyyy-MM-dd one (strictly, `yyyy-MM-dd[Thh:mm:ss[.f*]][Z|+hh:mm|-hh:mm]`) in every country in the world except (last time I looked) Norway and North Korea (I think Norway may have adopted it too, since). dd-mm-yyyy is a local convention in some places, not a standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DateTime.Now.ToString(@"yyyy\-MM\-dd hh\-mm\-ss.000")` though are you sure you don't want `DateTime.Now.ToString(@"yyyy\-MM\-dd hh\:mm\:ss.000")`?

Comment: thank you for the correction , your second line of the answer is correct :) thanks

Comment: why are you using backslash before `-` and `:`?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, the `:` is escaped because it's the indicator of the locale-specific time-separator so while it could be rendered as `:` it could also be e.g. `.` in an Italian locale. The `-` is escaped just to be explicit that it's a literal and not a code (also means there's no need to remember what you must escape). I would also e.g. escape the T in `yyyy\-MM\-dd\Thh\:mm\:ss` even though it also doesn't need it. (Somehow though `\.\0\0\0` just seemed like too much typing!).

Comment: Thanks Jon, didn't know the `:` in the DateTime `ToString()` is "reserved"!

Comment: Yeah, the fact that output in many locales is ":" doesn't help that be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I simply don't believe you. Simple string concatenation isn't going to start messing around with the rest of the string.

Here's a short but complete example showing it *not* changing:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string currTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("u");
        currTime = currTime.Substring(0, currTime.Length - 1);
        currTime = currTime + ".000";
        Console.WriteLine(currTime);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2011-03-22 12:28:39.000
```

I don't think that's the best way of coming up with that format, but it certainly isn't behaving the way you claim. Can you come up with a similar short but complete program which backs up your assertion that "this then removes the formatting and display it as the standard dd-mm-yyyy format"? My guess is that you're not seeing what you actually *think* you're seeing, but without a complete program it's hard to tell what's really going on.

Comment: My guess is that its being replaced with `DateTime.Now + ".000"`, perhaps with a `DateTime` value called `curTime` or similar, which would hide the mistake, and result in the equivalent of `DateTime.Now.ToString("G", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) + ".000"`

Comment: @Jon: Possibly. It would be interesting to hear from the OP about it... I suspect they could learn something either about debugging or asking for help if they worked out what was happening...

Comment: Agreed. While I don't think their approach was the best anyway (hence my answer being completely different), it does seem that they couldn't possibly have had the effects they described from the code they described.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to do the trick, with the slight alteration that appends the *actual* fraction of seconds rather than a hard-coded `.000`:

```
var result = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff}", DateTime.Now);
```